# A pop-up JavaScript code generated in my site without my knowledge

Tags: popup

I have a website built with custom PHP. From last week when I click on any link to my site a pop-up opens itself. When I checked my code I found an unknown JavaScript code in header of my site like:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
var uid = '67478';
var wid = '124210';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.popcash.net/pop.js"></script>
```

I removed this code but next day I rechecked, again same code in header. I again removed it but this comes back again and again.

What is this and how can I remove it permanently?

Comment: Removing write access to this file might help. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have very serious issue, Some one is injecting that script and earning money of your site.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

check your site against `XSS injection`